# What are the best growing conditions for Vanilla planfolia?

Tags: plant-care, orchids, optimal-conditions

As part of my creation of a tropical growth room to grow some vanilla orchids, I was wondering if anybody knew the optimal conditions to grow this plant.

I would need:

1. Humidity
2. Temperature
3. Watering levels
4. Daylight hours

Thank you very much,
Tropical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## On the care and requirements of *Vanilla planfolia*

- **Humidity:** Over 50% is optimal. These plants thrive in very high humidity. However, steam is a little much. Try to keep it between 50 and 90% rh. 65-70% is ideal.
- **Temperature:** *Vanilla planfolia* likes a daytime temperature of 80-85 degrees Fahrenheit, while at night, they prefer a temperature of 60-65 degrees Fahrenheit.
- **Watering levels:** If the plant is in a potting medium, keep it moist at all times, if growing on a substrate, the plants roots and areal roots should be sprayed often, and never allowed to dry out. The leaves can occasionally be sprayed also.
- **Daylight hours:** The plant requires 1500-3000 foot-candles all day, and in nature this will be 12-16 hours per day.

References:

1. Home Guides: http://homeguides.sfgate.com/care-vanilla-bean-orchid-54771.html
2. Orchid Flowers: http://orchidflowers.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/tips-to-grow-vanilla-plant/
3. Akatsuka Orchid Gardens: http://www.akatsukaorchid.com/store/pg/51-Vanilla-Orchid-Care.aspx
4. Carter and Holmes Orchids: http://carterandholmes.com/vanillacare.html
5. OrchidTalk Forum: http://www.rv-orchidworks.com/orchidtalk/general-orchid-culture/11473-growing-vanilla-planifolia.html
6. About.com: http://flowers.about.com/od/OrchidFlowers/p/Vanilla-Orchid-Care-The-Vanilla-Bean-Plant.htm
7. Doityourself.com: http://www.doityourself.com/stry/caring-for-your-vanilla-bean-plant#b
8. Fairchild Tropical Botanic Garden: http://www.fairchildgarden.org/livingcollections/tropicalfruitprogram/jackfruit/vanilla-Orchild/
9. Everything Orchids: http://everything-orchids.com/types-of-orchids/vanilla-orchid
10. Orchid Care Tips: http://www.orchid-care-tips.com/vanilla-orchid.html
11. OrchidCareLady.com: http://www.orchidcarelady.com/orchids-care-and-maintenance-tips-vanilla-orchids/
12. Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla
13. vanillaplantations.com: http://www.vanillaplantations.com/cultivation.htm
14. Orchids Made Easy: http://www.orchidsmadeeasy.com/vanilla-orchid/
15. Vegetable Gardener: http://www.vegetablegardener.com/item/12993/the-vanilla-bean-orchid
16. Gardening Know How: http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/orchids/grow-vanilla-orchid.htm